# In BlackBerry LED why stops

Tags: blackberry

I am adding a custom LED color in BlackBerry programmatically using LED.etColorPattern(int[] pattern, boolean repeat) method.
LED start successfully.
But when any system event occur and deice goes to start RED color LED (which is default) color for system events, then my custom LED stops, instead of blinking both my custom LED
and system default LED (RED).

Please tell me what is the reason.???

Answer (score 1):

The LED can blink with one color at a time. When a system event occurs, and after this system event, you start your own LED color, it will replace the system's LED color. In reverse when you make that LED colored, the system will override it when an event occurs. You can't manage to keep the color you wish for your LED anytime, especially when a system event occurs.

You can resolve this by making your LED color red. In that case this color will not change. Or you will have to accept the fact that the color will become red when another event occurs